# Java HTMLUnit get button without value or id

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to click a button on a website using HTMLUnit and i can't seem to figure how to do it! The button looks like this:

```
<p class="submit">
<button class="button" tabindex="3" type="submit">create account</button>
<span class="throbber"></span>
<span class="status" style="display: none;"></span>
</p>
```

I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work. 
Can anyone help me out with this!?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really easy in HtmlUnit. When you have the page, you can find all buttons with `page.getElementsByTagName("button")`. Filter the list by the attribute `type` because there should be only a single `submit` button per form.

Comment: i've tried to  `page.getElementsByTagName("button")` and the DomNodeList is empty!!

Comment: Well, in that case, there are no buttons on that page... Make sure you have the correct page. Try to get some other nodes that should exist.

Answer (score 2):

In HtmlUnit, You can use

i. querySelector

```
HtmlElement button = Page.querySelector('.button');
```

ii. XPath

```
HtmlElement button = Page.getFirstbyXPath("//span[@class='button']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `page.querySelector("button.button")`. [Query selector](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#querySelector%28java.lang.String%29) searches by CSS selector. `.button` would probably work as well.